# Calling function from anonymous function in JQuery returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope

I'm working with this script which needs to call the external function, but the value returned in the log shows 'undefined'.
I have a checkbox that calls the external function successfully, but the anonymous jQuery function is not successful.  Could this be a scope issue of some sort?

Thanks for any help.

css:

```
div.row {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100px;
}
div.child {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

javascript:

```
function padZeros(ksa) {
    getDigits(ksa);
    //alert(s); 
    //document.getElementById("ksa_padded").value=s
}

function getDigits(MyDigits) {
    var ksa = MyDigits;
    var re4Digit = /^([0-9])([0-9]?)([k|s|a])([0-9])([0-9]?)([A-z]?)$/;
    var first2Digits = ksa.replace(re4Digit, "$1$2");
    //alert(first2Digits);
    //return first2Digits;
    pad(first2Digits, '2');
}

function pad(num, size) {
    //var s = num+"";
    //alert(num);
    s = num + "";
    //alert(s);
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
    //alert(s);

}

$("#add").click(function () {
    var inserted = false;
    var newText = $("#addText").val();
    var $newItem = $("<div class='child'>" + newText + "</div>");
    $(".row:first .child").each(function () {
        //alert($(this).text());
        xx = $(this).text();
        var compare_a = padZeros(xx);
        //alert(compare_a);
        console.log(xx);

        if ($(this).text() > newText) {
            $newItem.insertBefore($(this));
            inserted = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (inserted == false) {
        $newItem.appendTo(".row:first");
    }
});
```

html

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="child">3K1</div>
     <div class="child">3K3</div>
     <div class="child">3K4</div>
     <div class="child">1K1</div>
     <div class="child">1K2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="child">IS2</div>
     <div class="child">IS4</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="child">IA2</div>
     <div class="child">IA4</div>
 </div>
 <br/>
 <input id="addText" type="text" />
 <input id="add" type="button" value="Insert Element" />
 <br>

 <input type="checkbox" onClick="padZeros('1k10s')">
 <input type="text" id="ksa_padded">
```

Comment: If you don't have your source code indented properly, at least run it through http://jsbeautifier.org/ before you post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return getDigits(ksa);
return pad(first2Digits,'2');
```

You have to return things, otherwise they'll come out as `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks.  I've added those in my getDigits and pad functions, but I'm still getting the 'undefined'.  
When I test just those functions, calling the PadZero function from an onclick event, the value returns successfully.  It's only when I try calling PadZero from within the anonymous function that 'undefined' occurs.

Comment: @buck1112 `.text()` must be undefined.  Try logging `$(this)` and look at the output.

Comment: yes, it is.  It is only when I call the function that it becomes undefined, however, as below. 
    `console.log(padZeros($(this).text()));`

Comment: @buck1112 Is it undefined when you `padZeros('1k10s')` in the anonymous function?

Comment: Yes it is.  I tried logging the variable, as well as `padZeros('1k10s')` directly, but they both returned 'undefined'.  Thanks.

Comment: @buck1112 I'll have to look more into this.  Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Doorknob Because reasons. Will explain